# signin callback is not being triggered in nextauth

Tags: mongodb, next.js, oauth, next-auth

I am working with google provider in my `next js` project with `next auth` and `mongoDb`. During `signin with google` the *{name, email, id , image, emailVerified}* fields are automatically written into database inside users collection and it is provided as session.

I want to remove the `name and image` fields from users collection (Which was written by nextauth into my users collection) and add the `name and image`  in `usersdetails` collection with `user:user_id` as reference field to user collection.

ie: `userdetails: {users:userId(ref: users), name:"sth", image:"url"}`

For that I  wrote code to migrate data fields from users collection to userdetails collection into the `signin` callback but seems like the `signin` callback is not being triggered as even the `console.log` is not being shown in server console.

My `api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js` looks like this:

```
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";
import Users from "@/models/useraccounts/users";
import UsersDetails from "@/models/useraccounts/usersDetail";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"

const authOptions = {
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    pages: {
        // signIn: "/auth/login"
    },
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // in seconds
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    // database: "",
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            session.user = token.user;
            return session;
        },

        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = user;
            }
            return token;
        },

        async signin({ profile, account }) {
            console.log("SIGNING IN+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
            if (account.provider === "google") {
                try {
                    await dbConnect(); // connection to database

                    const user = await Users.findOne({ email: profile.email }); //finding if user with the signed email is in users collection

                    if (user && user.name != null && user.image != null) {// if this condition is satisfied then it is first google signup as on the first google signup the name and image field is removed from users collection
                        // Move the 'name' and 'image' fields to UserDetails
                        const userDetails = await UsersDetails.findOne({ user: user._id });

                        if (!userDetails) {
                            const details = {
                                name: user.name,
                                photo: user.image,
                                user: user._id,
                            };

                            const newUserDetails = new UsersDetails(details);
                            await newUserDetails.save();
                        } else {
                            userDetails.name = user.name;
                            userDetails.photo = user.image;
                            await userDetails.save();
                        }

                        // Update user document to remove 'name' and 'image' fields
                        const updatedUser = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {isSeller:false, emailVerified:true, $unset: { name: 1, image: 1 } }, {new:true});

                        // Return only 'id' and 'emailVerified' in the session
                        
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error while migrating user data:", error);
                    throw error;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },

    },
}



const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

**Is this method correct ?  What is wrong with my code/method?**

Answer (score 0):

**Didn't Know why the `signin` callback was not triggered**

BUT

Solved my problem where I have to save my few details {email, emailVerified} to users collection and other details {name, image} to userDetails.

I achieved that by modifying the database adapter.

The modified adapter looks like this:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
export const defaultCollections = {
    Users: "users",
    Accounts: "accounts",
    Sessions: "sessions",
    VerificationTokens: "verification_tokens",
    UsersDetails: "usersdetails",
};
export const format = {
    /** Takes a mongoDB object and returns a plain old JavaScript object */
    from(object) {
        const newObject = {};
        for (const key in object) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (key === "_id") {
                newObject.id = value.toHexString();
            }
            else if (key === "userId") {
                newObject[key] = value.toHexString();
            }
            else {
                newObject[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return newObject;
    },
    /** Takes a plain old JavaScript object and turns it into a mongoDB object */
    to(object) {
        const newObject = {
            _id: _id(object.id),
        };
        for (const key in object) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (key === "userId")
                newObject[key] = _id(value);
            else if (key === "id")
                continue;
            else
                newObject[key] = value;
        }
        return newObject;
    },
};
/** @internal */
export function _id(hex) {
    if (hex?.length !== 24)
        return new ObjectId();
    return new ObjectId(hex);
}

export function MongoDBAdapter(client, options = {}) {
    const { collections } = options;
    const { from, to } = format;
    const db = (async () => {
        const _db = (await client).db(options.databaseName);
        const c = { ...defaultCollections, ...collections };
        return {
            U: _db.collection(c.Users),
            UD: _db.collection(c.UsersDetails),
            A: _db.collection(c.Accounts),
            S: _db.collection(c.Sessions),
            V: _db.collection(c?.VerificationTokens),
        };
    })();
    return {
        async createUser(data) {
            const { email, name, image, emailVerified } = data;
            const user = to({email, emailVerified});
            const userDetails = to({name, image});
            await (await db).U.insertOne(user);
            await (await db).UD.insertOne(userDetails);
            return from(user);
        },
        async getUser(id) {
            const user = await (await db).U.findOne({ _id: _id(id) });
            if (!user)
                return null;
            return from(user);
        },
        async getUserByEmail(email) {
            const user = await (await db).U.findOne({ email });
            if (!user)
                return null;
            return from(user);
        },
        async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
            const account = await (await db).A.findOne(provider_providerAccountId);
            if (!account)
                return null;
            const user = await (await db).U.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(account.userId) });
            if (!user)
                return null;
            return from(user);
        },
        async updateUser(data) {
            const { _id, ...user } = to(data);
            const result = await (await db).U.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { $set: user }, { returnDocument: "after" });
            return from(result);
        },
        async deleteUser(id) {
            const userId = _id(id);
            const m = await db;
            await Promise.all([
                m.A.deleteMany({ userId: userId }),
                m.S.deleteMany({ userId: userId }),
                m.U.deleteOne({ _id: userId }),
            ]);
        },
        linkAccount: async (data) => {
            const account = to(data);
            await (await db).A.insertOne(account);
            return account;
        },
        async unlinkAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
            const account = await (await db).A.findOneAndDelete(provider_providerAccountId);
            return from(account);
        },
        async getSessionAndUser(sessionToken) {
            const session = await (await db).S.findOne({ sessionToken });
            if (!session)
                return null;
            const user = await (await db).U.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(session.userId) });
            if (!user)
                return null;
            return {
                user: from(user),
                session: from(session),
            };
        },
        async createSession(data) {
            const session = to(data);
            await (await db).S.insertOne(session);
            return from(session);
        },
        async updateSession(data) {
            const { _id, ...session } = to(data);
            const updatedSession = await (await db).S.findOneAndUpdate({ sessionToken: session.sessionToken }, { $set: session }, { returnDocument: "after" });
            return from(updatedSession);
        },
        async deleteSession(sessionToken) {
            const session = await (await db).S.findOneAndDelete({
                sessionToken,
            });
            return from(session);
        },
        async createVerificationToken(data) {
            await (await db).V.insertOne(to(data));
            return data;
        },
        async useVerificationToken(identifier_token) {
            const verificationToken = await (await db).V.findOneAndDelete(identifier_token);
            if (!verificationToken)
                return null;
            const { _id, ...rest } = verificationToken;
            return rest;
        },
    };
}
```

No more changes. The changes are:

1. Added `UsersDetails` to default collection.
2. Modified return value for `db` function to return *userdetails* collection
   along with other collections.
3. Modified `createUser` function to store data
   separately in two different collections

.

PS: Adapters can be edited as per your need.